# jQuery radio button selection/deselection

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm currently using jQuery on some radio buttons.  When the user clicks a radio, a function is called that removes the `checked` attribute from all other radios and disables input fields associated with other radios.  For example, when one radio is clicked,

```
  function EnableRadio1() {
    $('#x :input').attr('checked', false).attr('disabled', true);
    $('#y :input').attr('checked', false).attr('disabled', true);
    $('#z :input').attr('checked', false).attr('disabled', true);
    $('#n :input').attr('checked', false).attr('disabled', true);

    //enable segs_by_all options
    $('#radio1 :input').removeAttr('disabled');   
  }
```

is called by my Rails helper,
`<%= radio_button_tag 'users', 'all', false, :id => 'radio1', :onclick => 'EnableRadio1()' %>`
What's a more succinct and jQueryesque way to do this?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you...

```
$(".radio").change(function(){
    $(":radio").not(this).attr({"checked": false, "disabled": true});
    $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
});
```